# Eulerean and Hamiltonian cycles on 5 vertices

Tags: graph-theory

how to draw a graph with 5 vertices which is:

a)Eulerian cycle but not Hamiltonnian cycle.
b)Hamiltonnian cycle but not Eulerian cycle.
c)Eulerian cycle and Hamiltonnian cycle.

Comment: please help me answer this question

Comment: Write down the definitions of a Eulerian and Hamiltonian cycle and it should be quite easy with some trials. Do you remember the characterisation of Eulerian graphs ?

Comment: Eulerian cycle-accessible all node once and again,compulsory cross every node       while Hamiltonian cycle-node must be pass through once only ,can skip node.

Comment: No, Eulerian cycles use all edges and return to start.  Hamiltonian cycles use all vertices once each and return to start.

Answer (score 2):

Two days later, this is probably worth an answer.

If your points are A, B, C, D, E then the edges AB, BC, CD, DE, EA clearly provide one of the smallest graphs which has both a [Eulerian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_cycle) and [Hamiltonian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_cycle).

Add another edge, for example AC, and you have a graph which has the same Hamiltonian cycle but not an Eulerian cycle, since A and C have an odd number of edges.

Alternatively, the edges AB, BC, CA, AD, DE, EA, provide a Eulerian cycle but not a Hamiltonian cycle, since you can only get from B to D via A, and you cannot get back without visiting A again.

Incidentally, the neat Flash game at http://neamar.fr/Res/Icosien/ asks you to find 20 Eulerian cycle and Hamiltonian cycles for given graphs.